# C++ Header File Error: Base Class Undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am currently getting a lot of frustration with including header file in my starting project. so far i have a header files linked to my base file and I keep getting the same error that the compilation cannot read my base class.

I believe that there is a problem with reading the header file. What should I do?

//Update now it is showing compilation error with the build

**Main cpp file**

```
#include <string>
#include "animal.h"
using namespace std;
enum COLOR { Green, Blue, White, Black, Brown };

int main() {

cout << "Starting" << endl;
int value = 0; Mammal *zoo[3];
int i = 0;

cout << "Program exiting …. " << endl;
return 0;
}
```

**Header file**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

using namespace std;
enum COLOR { Green, Blue, White, Black, Brown };

class Animal {
public:
Animal() {
    cout << "constructing Animal object " << _name << endl;
}
~Animal() {
    cout << "destructing Animal object " << _name << endl;
}

Animal(std::string n, COLOR c) {
    _name = n; _color = c;
    cout << "constructing " << _name << " Color " <<
        endl;
}

virtual void speak() const { cout << "Animal speaks " << endl; }
//void speak() const { cout << "Animal speaks " << endl; }
virtual void move() = 0;

void setName(std::string n) { _name = n; }
void setCOLOR(COLOR c) { _color = c; }

private:
std::string _name; COLOR _color;
};

class Mammal : public Animal {
public:
Mammal() {}
Mammal(std::string n, COLOR c) {
    setName(n);
    setCOLOR(c);
    cout << "constructing Mammal object " <<  endl;
}
~Mammal() { cout << "destructing Mammal object " << endl; }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Shouldn't `COLOR` be declared in `animal.h` before you use it?

Comment: `COLOR` is defined in cpp file and not visible in header, you are using `cout` and other stuff from `std` namespace in header file without properly prepending `::std::`.

Answer (score 0):

using `pragma once` and include guards together is redundant. Remove either one.

If you use `string` in the header, do not forget that it needs `std::` prefix.

`COLOR` must be moved to the header file.

```
// #pragma once
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

using namespace std;
enum COLOR { Green, Blue, White, Black, Brown };
```

You also need to define `setName`

**In conclusion:**

In C and C++, every type or function must be declared or defined first then used and not the vice versa.

Comment: It is not redundant, using `pragma once` and header guards together may have different effects than using only one of them.

Comment: @VTT, are you talking about typical practical usage?

Comment: @ArashMohammadi _"do not forget `using namespace std` in the header file ..."_ Worst advice I could think of.

Comment: @user0042, I totally agree. but he must write all `std::` headers. Just a quick way to make the code compilable.

Comment: @ArashMohammadi Better _"quick way"_: `using std::string;`

Comment: Currently still not fixed, after using the same namespace for all files, applying the enum to header file and defining the method. Error is still mammal base class undefined. Sorry I'm a beginner programmer here..